# How to merge two different vcf files with different samples' number on R?

Tags: r, merge, rbind, vcf-variant-call-format

I have two different vcf files with snps from different samples (119 samples in vcf file n1 and 21 in vcf file n2).I'd like to have a single vcf file with same meta and combined fixed and gt region.

I tried to use this command:

```
vcf_full <- rbind(vcf1, vcf2)
```

but resulted in this error:

> Error in rbind(x@gt, y@gt) :  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)

My two vcf file have, indeed, different columns' number since there is a different number of samples. I'm very confused at this point and I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: I would suggest using bcftools merge

Comment: I used: 

bcftools merge -o pop_snp140.vcf.gz -O z pop_snp120_sorted.vcf.gz pop_snp20_sorted.vcf.gz

The REF prefixes differ: T vs C (1,1)
Failed to merge alleles at NC_050096.1:306194 in pop_snp20_sorted.vcf.gz

Then I tried to add 'id' after the function '-m' and it worked, but I had problems using the vcf files for further analysis on R, so I'm trying to merge the VCF on R.

Comment: Show us `dim(vcf1)` and `dim(vcd2)`

Comment: dim(vcf1) --> variants: 1329850, fix_cols: 8, gt_cols: 120.  dim(vcf2) -->variants:  398167, fix_cols: 8, gt_cols: 22 
@IRTFM

Comment: You might try the Bioconductor.org help forum.